# Replace a string several times with a regex (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
<li><a class="amshopby-attr-selected" href="">1</a> (320)</li>
<li><a class="amshopby-attr" href="">2</a> (2)</li>
<li><a class="amshopby-attr" href="">3</a> (1)</li>
```

I want to replace the **a class="amshopby-attr-selected" href** with something else in the whole string (each line). I tried using `"<a class="amshopby-attr-selected" href"` as regex, but this only finds and replaces it once. How can I replace all at once?

Thanks! :)

Comment: What language are you using? JavaScript, PHP,... ?

Comment: In the end its JavaScript.

Comment: Have you used the `/g` modifier?

Comment: look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285472/multiple-regex-replace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to specify the `g` modifier to indicate a *global* search. Otherwise, the regular expression will only match once.

```
var replaced = original.replace(/<a class="amshopby-attr-selected" href"/g, substitute);
```